# Z-order issue with a modal dialog

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, z-order

I've created a dialog to an existing application (which I'm not aware of its entire structure), and the dialog is keep maintaining the highest Z-order **OF ALL WINDOWS SHOWN IN THE OS** instead of highest within the application.

Here's a rough sketch of how I'm implementing it:

Message map `ON_COMMAND` links the menu to the handler function `OnTestDialog()`, which looks like this:

```
void CSettle3DDoc::OnTestDialog(){
    UpdateAllViews(NULL);
    CDlg_Test_Dialog dlg;
    dlg.DoModal();
}
```

`CDlg_Test_Dialog` is a subclass of `ETSLayoutDialog`, which you can find the code here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/116/Layout-Manager-for-Dialogs-Formviews-DialogBars-an

From there, `::OnInitDialog()` calls on `ETSLayoutDialog::OnInitDialog()`, and initializes other variable that has noting to do with the Z-order.

After initialization, there are no other code that causes the Dialog's Z-order to change.
Staying on top of other windows within the application is acceptable, but blocking other applications' view is a bit annoying, and I'd like it to be fixed :(

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the dialog box template you're using have the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` style bit set?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, I checked, and it was set to 1. Still, isn't this flag also used on other modal dialog as well to keep them on top "within the application"?

Comment: Nope, `WS_EX_TOPMOST` works across the whole desktop. Modal dialogs stay on top of their parents "naturally".

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I see. I added `::SetWindowPos(diagHwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOREDRAW);` inside `OnInitDialog()`, and it's now working properly. Thank you so much :D

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Almost correct. But it's not the *parent*, it's called the *owner*. Owned windows (dialogs or others) are always in front of their owner.

Comment: @Caladbolgll: The correct solution would be to remove the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` style from your dialog resource. If you insist that you must dynamically remove the style bit, call [SetWindowLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx) with index `GWL_EXSTYLE` instead.

Comment: @IInspectable: I can't find that parameter in the VS dialog editor, and I failed to find where that flag was being set from debugging :( Do you have a clue for where I might find this being set?

Comment: If you can't find it in the resource editor, edit the [Resource File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599.aspx) manually. By default it has an .rc file extension.